# How do I echo more than one object from post in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object, post

Im not to familiar with php.

I am posting from a form and my php looks like this :

```
// Object syntax looks better and is easier to use than arrays to me
    $post = new stdClass;

    // Usually there would be much more validation and filtering, but this
    // will work for now.
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
        $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
```

On the form I have fields like Fist Name, Last Name , Address, Zip, City, State etc.

The information will displayed in a table on my next page (for example) with:

```
<?php echo $post->name; ?>
```

since I am using the object syntax.

If I want the cell that displays the address to combine the full address do I write it like this:

```
<?php echo $post->address, city, state, zip; ?>
```

I basically would like to show the address as an address would normally be displayed (e.g. 123 This street, City, AZ, 55555)

Ideally, it would be comma separated as an address would be written. So I am sure I am not do this correctly right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars("{$post->address}, {$post->city}, {$post->state}, {$post->zip}"); ?>
```

The curly braces allow you to enclose PHP object references within a string (rather than having to use concatenation).

Comment: This seemed to work perfectly and everyone's posts were helpful. So is the comma made because it is outside of the braces? Looks exactly the way I was wanting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$post->` everytime you want to reference a property from it. The different parameters of `echo` will concatenate the strings. So if you wanted to show those properties, separated by comas:

```
<?php echo $post->address, ',', $post->city, ',', $post->state, ',', $post->zip; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If the order of the items in the post object is the order you need:

```
echo implode(', ', (array) $post);
```

If not, you need to do it outlined as in the many other answers, for example:

```
echo "{$post->address}, {$post->city}, {$post->state}, {$post->zip}";
```

An important point is missing however if you output into HTML:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(implode(', ', (array) $post));
```

resp:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("{$post->address}, {$post->city}, {$post->state}, {$post->zip}");
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd have an `Address` object within your `Post` object. So it would look as follows:

```
class Post {
    var $title;
    var $address;
}

class Address {
    var $street_address;
    var $locality;
    var $region;
    var $postal_code;

    function __toString() {
        return implode(', ', array($this->street_address, $this->locality, $this->region, $this->postal_code));
    }
}

$address = new Address($street_address, $locality, $region, $postal_code);
$post    = new Post('title', $address);
```

You can then grab your address with commas like thus:

```
<p id="address"><?php echo $post->address; ?></p>
```

The `address` property would be an instance of your `Address` object, and as you echo it, it will call that object's `__toString` magic method, outputting the address components separated by commas.

Comment: I love it when people actually use classes. . . even if you aren't quite doing it correctly.

Comment: You can get all the object variables with get_object_vars($this). . . They'll be in the same order as you defined them.  And I wouldn't use the toString method.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create variable variables like so:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    ${$key} = trim( strip_tags($val) );
}

echo "$street, $city, $state, $zip";
```

Check the full code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/MMpSVjNv

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $post->address.", ".$post->city.", ".$post->state.", ".$post->zip; ?>
```

the .-operator concats strings in php. 
you should take a look in a php-tutorial to get into the matter: http://tut.php-quake.net/en/

Answer (score 2):

Close, but not quite:

```
<?php echo $post->address, "<br>", $post->city, " ", $post->state, "<br>", $post->zip ?>
```

echo can take multiple comma-separated arguments. The alternative is to use multiple echo calls.